# Rails 5 includes eagerloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Photo model for which it's photos can be but in a Bucket model. The Bucket model is a subclass of a Facet model.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :facets
  has_one :bucket
end


class Facet < ApplicationRecord
  # validates_uniqueness_of :user, :scope => :photo_id
  belongs_to :photo
  belongs_to  :user
end

class Bucket < Facet
  belongs_to :photo
  belongs_to  :user
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: true
end
```

When I fetch a photo which is in the bucket, using include I would expect to get the Photo attributes + the Bucket attributes. But I only get the Photo attributes, I use include like this:

```
Photo.includes(:facets).find( 7)
```

The Facet table:

```
  create_table "facets", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci" do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "photo_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "type"
    t.string "comment"
    t.integer "tag_id"
    t.bigint "photos_id"
    t.index ["photos_id"], name: "index_facets_on_photos_id"
    t.index ["user_id", "type", "comment", "tag_id"], name: "index_facets_on_user_id_and_type_and_comment_and_tag_id", unique: true
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are getting the facets but you need to access them using the [association helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

`has_many :facets` creates an association method called `facets` on your individual `Photo` records.

Given:

```
photo = Photo.includes(:facets).find(7)
```

You can see the related facets by doing:

```
photo.facets
```